# Transition Event fires too soon on height transitioning

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JavaScript file which looks like this:

```
function hideIt(body_id, icon_id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(body_id);
    var y = document.getElementById(icon_id);
    if (x.style.height==="0px") {
        x.style.height= x.scrollHeight + 'px';
        x.addEventListener("webkitTransitionBegin", fullStyle(body_id));
        y.src = "<%= asset_path('show_icon.png') %>";
    } else {
        x.style.height= '0px';
        x.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", noStyle(body_id));
        y.src = "<%= asset_path('hide_icon.png') %>";
    }
}

function noStyle(body_id) {
  console.log("noStyle");
  var x = document.getElementById(body_id);
  x.style.padding = '0px';
  x.style.margin = '0px';
  x.style.border = 'none';
}

function fullStyle(body_id) {
  console.log("fullStyle");
  var x = document.getElementById(body_id);
  x.style.padding = '10px';
  x.style.marginBottom = '5px';
  x.style.marginTop = '5px';
  x.style.border = '1px solid #eaeaea';
}
```

The CSS for the elements which I manipualte looks like this:

```
.post-body-preview{
  color: $black;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1000ms;
}
```

The Problem now is that `noStyle` is triggered as soon as I click the icon with the `icon_id` which fires the `hideIt` script to hide the body. The Element `x` gets immediately stripped of its margins, paddings, and borders, thus `webkitTransitionEnd` is fired as soon as I press the button

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did this:

```
x.addEventListener("webkitTransitionBegin", fullStyle(body_id));
```

Instead of this:

```
x.addEventListener("webkitTransitionBegin", function(){ fullStyle(body_id); });
```

So it has always fired the function.